# Passing parameters from Django view to form not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to pass parameter from my createview to form, but that parameter is not received at the form. I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my view,

```
class ItemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
   form_class       = ItemForm
   template_name    = 'form.html'

   def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super(ItemCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs['user'] = self.request.user # pass the 'user' in kwargs
       return kwargs 

   def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
       context = super(ItemCreateView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['title'] = 'Add Items'
       return context

   def form_valid(self,form):
       instance = form.save(commit = False)
       instance.user = self.request.user
       instance.save()
       return super(ItemCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The following is my form class:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Item
from restaurants.models import RestaurantLocation

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields=[
        'name',
        'restaurant',
        'contents',
        'excludes',
        'public'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        print(user)
        super(ItemForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['restaurant'].queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

Comment: The code is all well,nothing print in forms.py?try to print(user.id) in both get_form_kwargs and ItemForm

Comment: have you override get_form method in CreateView?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help

Comment: So,what is the problem?

Comment: I was looking at the update view instead of create view. Thank you, for your time.

Comment: Can be closed under typo/unreproducible: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._